# When updating to macOS Catalina will the default Python installation get removed from my system?

Tags: macos, python, catalina

Apple [will stop shipping scripting languages like Python with macOS starting with Catalina](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/bwulrh/apple_will_soon_be_removing_python_perl_and_ruby/). When I eventually update to macOS Catalina, will the Python (2.7.X), which currently ships with macOS get removed from my system? Or is it only if I do a fresh install to Catalina that I won't get the Python installation anymore?

Comment: You should stop using that Python by 1/1/2020 anyway as it will stop being maintained

Comment: @Mark I hope many of the applications I'm using will stop relying on that by then.

Comment: "stop shipping scripting languages like Python" what the fuck, *WHY*?

Comment: @Alexander https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/bwulrh/apple_will_soon_be_removing_python_perl_and_ruby/

Comment: The reddit link (and the document linked there) does not support the claim that Apple will remove this with Catalina.

Comment: @nohillside Yeah, I realised that they will stop shipping them only in later macOSes only after I had asked the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Xcode 11 Beta Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_release_notes?language=objc):

> Scripting language runtimes such as Python, Ruby, and Perl are included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. **In future versions of macOS**, scripting language runtimes won’t be available by default, and may require you to install an additional package. If your software depends on scripting languages, it’s recommended that you bundle the runtime within the app. (49764202)

So in Catalina these runtimes will still be available.

Also, from the same document

> Use of Python 2.7 isn’t recommended. This version is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software. Future versions of macOS won’t include Python 2.7. Instead, it’s recommended that you run python3 in Terminal. (51097165)

Comment: Ok, so they will still ship with Catalina, even on fresh install? Any word on if they will ever get removed when **updating** to a newer OS?

Comment: It doesn't say "not included", only only is recommends to take action for future OS versions. So in Catalina they are still included (would be rather challenging otherwise).

Comment: Anyway, the usual recommendation of installing early betas on a separate partition/drive apply, so there is no risk in just trying :-)

Answer (score 2):

I installed MacOS Catalina Beta and it was packaged with scripting languages like python (2.7) and ruby. Python3 was not available.

So probably they might remove it in the next major release (10.16) or they might remove it in the stable version of 10.15. In the former case, everything would function as expected, I believe.

Comment: Okey! Python3 has never shipped with macOS, so that's a non issue.

Comment: @ruohola Are you sure about that? I'm on Catalina now, and I have a `/usr/bin/python3` that claims to be v3.7.3; this is in addition to a (newer) Homebrew install at `/usr/bin/local/python3`. **Edit:** I'm led to believe `python3` came with an XCode installation.

Comment: Hmm, I just checked myself and you are correct! I also have Python 3.7.3 as `/usr/bin/python3`.

Comment: @Michael yeah it must be from XCode command line tools.

Comment: I want to remove python 2 from my Mac. If it is possible do guide me how to make it happen

Comment: @IrurikSoftLabs Python 2 resides in /Systems directory which cannot be edited unless SIP is disabled (not recommended). There is a symlink from in /usr/bin/python which points to the Python inside /Systems directory. I think if you could edit the $PATH and remove the /usr/bin/python while adding others, we won't be able to access it through Terminal. btw why do you want to remove python2 ?

Comment: @pranav Yes! I did it the same way you told using $PATH and all worked fine. I was building iOS app developed in python3 and the building was picking the wrong python (system).